# Sublime Text 2. Autocomplete python `from`

Tags: python, django, import, sublimetext2, rope

I am using SublimeRope plugin. When I am typing `from foo.b` it displays the autocomplete dialog with random crap but what I am really looking for is to recognize `bar` module inside the `foo` package. However if I type `from foo import b` it immediately suggest me to import `bar` as a module. Which means Rope "knows" about that module. How can I configure my Sublime to help me suggest the imports when `from foo.b` ?

I am doing projects with django so the real example it wont me to autocomplete `from django.contrib.` but if I type `from django.contrib.auth.models import U` it suggest me to import user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should definitely be using [SublimeJEDI](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI) for Python autocompletion! There's no way around Jedi awesomeness.

This is just a Sublime Plugin for the [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) library (which is definitely better than Rope, but I'm biased because I'm the author).

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to what other have said [sublimecodeintel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) can help you with this. However to get it working with Django as you would like you have to add a configuration file pointing to django to your project. The instructions for how to do this are on the github page linked above. You'll add something similar to this:

```
    {
"Django":{
    "django":'/Users/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel)? It's available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control), and has this functionality. The initial indexing of your packages may take some time, but once it's all set (you may need to restart Sublime once or twice to get everything loaded) it works like a charm.

Comment: Seems like it mess up the Rope plugin which I use especially because of 'Go To Definition' function. Are there any way to use both of them or maybe just remove Rope? I use Sublime Text 2.

Comment: I haven't used SublimeRope, so I'm not sure how they conflict. Double-check the SublimeCodeIntel settings to see if `"sublime_auto_complete"` is set to `false`, and if it is then try setting it to `true`.